# pandas concat to merge list of dataframes to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have dataframes named a, b, c (and more), and I'd like to concat them with a datafram named d.

I'm doing as below:

```
a= pd.concat([a, d], axis = 0)
b= pd.concat([b, d], axis = 0)
c= pd.concat([c, d], axis = 0)
...
```

As I have more tham 3 dataframe a,b,c, I'm looking for some ways to do it faster, like in a loop for eg. I'm using code as below but it doesn't work:

```
for x in [a,b,c]:
    global d
    x = pd.concat([x, d], axis = 0)
```

Comment: You need to write your own merge function, where you check weather d is empty. If so return x, else: concat x and d as shown.

Comment: Instead of having your three dataframe stored in unique variables, could you instead store them to a list or a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'task':['one'],'label':['tag_01'] })
b = pd.DataFrame({'task':['one'],'label':['tag_01'] })
c = pd.DataFrame({'task':['one'],'label':['tag_01'] })
d = pd.DataFrame({'task':['two'],'label':['tag_02'] })
```

A common solution to iterate over dataframes while using their name is to use another list with dataframes names, then enumerate and get value of name by position:

```
# create a dict containing dfs
names = ['a','b','c']
dict_dfs = ({names[i]: df for i, df in enumerate([a, b, c])})
```

Now we can use `globals()` to generate desidered output.
The `globals()` method returns the dictionary of the current global symbol table. A symbol table is a data structure maintained by a compiler.

```
for i in dict_dfs:
    globals()[str(i)] = pd.concat([dict_dfs[i], d], axis = 0)
```

Results:

```
a
Out[1]: 
  task   label
0  one  tag_01
0  two  tag_02


b
Out[2]: 
  task   label
0  one  tag_01
0  two  tag_02


c
Out[3]: 
  task   label
0  one  tag_01
0  two  tag_02
```

Comment: I edited my aswer for your specific case.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta Ok